# Выбор чекбокса по клику на id="stroka"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
document.getElementById('stroka').onclick = raz;
function raz() {
  if($("#ch1").attr("checked") == 'checked') {  
    $('#ch1').removeAttr("checked");
  } else {
    $('#ch1').attr("checked","checked");
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divTableRow" id="stroka" onclick="raz()">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" id="ch1">
      <span class="checkbox-custom2"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableCell">27.04.2017</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">28.04.2017</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">118725-31521</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">MOBIS/HYUNDAI/KIA</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">ZA44BWD02ACA9601E</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">ПЛЕНКА ЗАЩИТНАЯ БОКОВОЙ НАКЛАДНАЯ</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">9 999</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">1 256 878, 00</div>
</div>
```

Данный скрипт работает только 1 раз: если чекбокса нет, то по клику на строке `id="stroka"` он проставляется; если уже есть - снимается. Но второй раз уже не работает и чекбокс не выбирается совсем.

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: так а зачем двойное объявление `document.getElementById('stroka').onclick = raz;`  и `<div class="divTableRow" id="stroka" onclick="raz()">` ? Чтоб прям точно при точно сработало?

Comment: На самом деле всё работает... просто галочку не отображает.... ты можешь убедиться в этом открыв консоль и проследить у элемента появление атрибута......... но в данном случае все делается проще: `function raz() {
  $("#ch1").prop("checked", !$("#ch1").prop("checked"));
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@АлексейШиманский прав дважды.

Во-первых, я убрал `onclick="raz()"` из `<div class="divTableRow" id="stroka" onclick="raz()">`.

Во-вторых, зачем добавлять аттрибуты самому, проверять их и тд., когда можно просто спросить `.checked`? И он тебе ответит, `checked` он или нет. И сюда же можно его засетать.

Итого:

```js
document.getElementById('stroka').onclick = raz;

function raz() {
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("ch1");
    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTableRow" id="stroka">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" id="ch1">
      <span class="checkbox-custom2"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableCell">27.04.2017</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">28.04.2017</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">118725-31521</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">MOBIS/HYUNDAI/KIA</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">ZA44BWD02ACA9601E</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">ПЛЕНКА ЗАЩИТНАЯ БОКОВОЙ НАКЛАДНАЯ</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">9 999</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">1 256 878, 00</div>
</div>
```